# VB.net Streamreader use across different subs

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am setting streamreader to populate a list and then when I encounter a formfeed, I process each page separately. My problem is when I go to another sub the streamreader info is lost. How to I make it link across different subs?

Example is posted below:

Public Sub cmdGet()

Do Until sr_Read.EndOfStream

```
                ClearVariables()
                line = sr_Read.ReadLine
                Populate_List()


                ParseRecord()
                Print_Output_Record()

                myList01.Clear()
                myList01.Add("")
            Loop
```

end Sub

Public Sub Populate_List()

```
line = SR_Read.ReadLine
Do While (Mid(line, 1, 1) <> Chr(12))
    myList01.Add(line)
    line = SR_Read.ReadLine
Loop
```

End Sub

Thank you for any assistance you can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting you have a problem with what's called variable scope.  Somewhere you had to declare that stream reader object...  Something like this...

Dim Sr_Read As New StreamReader("flename")

You want to make sure that it is declared at the top of the class file... e.g. NOT inside any of the subs.

Comment: The problem is the filename is taken from a dialog box so the filename is not the same all the time.